# Regular expression to check whether an address contains a PO BOX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression in java script below:

```
.*(?<![pP].?[oO].? [boxBOX]{3})
```

basically this is to check if an address contains any combination of PO BOX.
However it is not working in case of white spaces and some of the combinations below:
P.O. box 17432
poSt oFFice box 11111
box 222
p0 box 222

## 343 po box (space)

Comment: If all you need is to check whether the pattern matches anywhere inside the string, all you need is something like `if (!/p[\s.]*o[\s.]*box/i.test(s)) {return "No PO Box found";}`

Comment: Why use regex when javascript has a similar function? Take a  look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's about this:

```
/(p[.]?[o0][.]?|post\s*?office)\s*?box/gi
```

Here's what happening:

First () is a group of two options, we match one or the other

First is `p[.]?[o0][.]?` This means a 'p' followed by an optional '.' then an 'o' or '0' followed by an optional '.'

This will handle 'po', 'p.o.', 'po.', 'p.o'

Second part is `/(p[.]?o[.]?|` This is 'post office' with none or any number of whitespace characters between the words

Next bit `\s*?` This means none or any number of whitespace characters

Last is just matching the word 'box'

`gi` makes the search global and case insensitive

Comment: Could you explain your regex, what it does and how it answers the question?

Comment: Done. After rereading the question I'm not sure it handles all the cases. OP's regex and examples don't make the parameters clear. Perhaps he can make a list of variations.

Comment: Whoah!? What did you do? Haha. Put the original question back above and create a new one.